# What does this External Linkage directive mean?

Tags: c++, linkage

Can someone explain this note in *C++ primer 5th edition* to me:

> Note
>
> The functions that C++ inherits from the C library are permitted to be defined as C functions but are not required to be C functions—it’s up to each C++ implementation to decide whether to implement the C library functions in C or C++.

Comment: Well, the functions that C++ inherits from the C library are permitted to be defined as C functions but are not required to be C functions. It’s up to each C++ implementation to decide whether to implement the C library functions in C or C++.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, as it is asking about intricate details of C++. It has enough information. It can only be answered by someone knowledgeable in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example of one function, that could be "treated" as C or C++. `std::toupper()` can also be written as `toupper()`. I believe the first one uses some safety checks of C++, while the other one is strictly `C`. But what it boils down to is:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    char c = 'b';

    std::cout << toupper(c);                                                                     

    return 0;
}
```

compiles using C way, while:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    char c = 'b';

    std::cout << std::toupper(c);                                                                     

    return 0;
}
```

Uses C++ compilation addressing namespaces, ant that is what @numzero's answer talks about.

Now both will compile, but it is up to you and your own risk to use `C` function.

Comment: Your should be including proper headers to discuss it compiling or not. Otherwise both version are at your own risk.

Comment: Um, where did you find *that* `toupper`? `std::toupper` is not a member function, it can’t use `this`, neither can it be `const`. That’s probably something from char_traits.

Comment: @numzero you were right, it was this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/libstdc++/api/a00389_source.html

Answer (score -2):

There are functions like `printf` which are defined in the C standard library but are required to be usable in C++ as well. However, C and C++ differ in how they link modules together: in C, functions are matched by name only, but in C++ full signature is normally used¹ ². But to allow interoperability, it is possible (using `extern "C"`) to force a C++ function to use C linkage so that it will match the identically-named C function (definition may be on either side).

What the quoted statement seems to state is that the functions that C++ inherits from the C standard library *may* be the actual C functions, but that is not required. They are also allowed to be defined as regular C++ functions (behaving equivalently, but not strictly identical, to the C counterparts) in C++.

¹ That is needed to support overloading; things return value type may not be used as it doesn’t participate in overload resolution.

² There might be some other differences as well.

Comment: The quoted text that the question asks about doesn’t mention linkage. It’s about implementation.

Comment: Well, I might misunderstand it. The question title does mention linkage.